# how to parse this python code django template language

Tags: django-templates

```py
 for com in applications:
            for number in range(len(appliers)):
                    if connector[number] == com.id:
                        print(appliers[number].name)
```

I am having problem with parsing this python code to django template language... keep getting error saying that it can't parse. please can anyone parse it for me...

Comment: How are you 'parsing it to template language'?

Comment: {% for number in range.appliers|length  %}
            {% if connector.number == commission.id %}
            {{appliers.number.name}}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter for getting a range in template:

```py
@register.filter(name='times') 
def times(number):
    return range(number)
```

And then in template you can do:

```py
{% for number in appliers|length|times %} 
    {% if connector.number == commission.id %} 
        {{appliers.number.name}} 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you can pass `range(len(appliers))` as a context variable to your template from a view.